# How to handle sockets in Java with Akka actors?

Tags: java, sockets, akka

I found tons of examples how to handle sockets in Scala with Akka actors, but there is no IO in the Java API. How should I use sockets in Java from within an Akka actor? Is there any wrapper around sockets that makes possible to communicate with the sockets using messages?

Answer (score 0):

The IO module only provides an api for Scala. The [IOManager](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/io.html#IOManager) may not be too hard to use from Java, you just have to handle the case classes it sends for each event type. The [IO.Iteratee](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/io.html#IO_Iteratee) would probably be trickier to use from Java code, so you might just avoid using that.